# how do I use GET to send multiple parametere to a url with port number

Tags: linux, curl, get

I have tried curl -X GET url:port then parameter but it gives me an erro
The site http://URL:PORTnumber only accepts HTTP GET requests. Send it a request that includes all three of the below paramater:value

usertype:admin
school:baruch
access-level:super duper

Answer (score 0):

Command should be something like this:

> curl -X GET http://192.168.1.1:9999/index.html?usertype=admin&school=baruch&access-level=super%20duper

- You must change the IP address to the real IP address or DNS name.
- You must change port number to the real port number.
- You must change index.html to the real name of the webpage.